# Help finding text by Liang Qichao

Tags: resources

I need the text 戊戌政變記 to cite some characteristic remarks about Cixi. Ctext has it [here](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=en&file=19266&page=2), but the OCR is horrible (of the order of one in three characters wrong). I went back to the plates and corrected many mistakes on selected pages, but they are very unclear and it is extremely time consuming to read them. Wikisource has a copy [here](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E6%88%8A%E6%88%8C%E6%94%BF%E8%AE%8A%E8%A8%98), but most of the chapters are empty. Does anyone know a more trustworthy online source?

Comment: How's wikisource: https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E6%88%8A%E6%88%8C%E6%94%BF%E8%AE%8A%E8%A8%98?

Comment: @ludi, if you have time, i would recommend another book, which is more interesting, imo :) 庚子西狩叢談 http://www.bnasie.eu/Asset/Source/bnBook_ID-1028_No-1.pdf

Comment: volume 3 of 庚子西狩叢談, page 82 onward (of the pdf),  written about the author met with empress dowager, a vivid account.

Comment: @ludi, thanks for the bounty. may i ask, you're doing an assignment?

Comment: my salute :) i've impression that "foreigners" understand the history / culture better than most chinese.

Comment: yes, even for me, i think that the literary chinese aft-opium-war are, quite difficult to read :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this pdf file:

http://www.bnasie.eu/Asset/Source/bnBook_ID-1505_No-01.pdf

it's reprinted in traditional chinese, vertical layout.

have fun :)